# Cancel bubbling on an HTML anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I have the following set-up on my webpage

```
<div id="clickable">
  <a href="hello.com">Here!</a>
</div>
```

Is there a way I could use to avoid the click event for the div to be triggered. I presume it has something to do with setting something in the `onclick` attribute for the anchor tag but trying simple things like `e.preventDefault()` haven't worked.

Help? Thanks!

Comment: You may want to add the [tag:javascript] tag, and, if you're using a library, the relevant tag for that library ([tag:jquery],[tag:mootools],etc...).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

e.preventDefault(); wont work in onclick attributes because e is not defined. Also e.preventDefault(); isn't want you want to stop bubbling, you need e.stopPropagation();

Either use;

```
onclick="$(this).stopPropagation();"
```

on your anchor, or

```
$(a).click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

in your events.

Comment: A note for future readers, this answer is using jQuery syntax. See @Poison Oak's answer for a Vanilla JS solution

Answer (score 6):

Vanilla JS expansion on the accepted answer. `event.stopPropagation()` is the most specific and predictable method for preventing events from bubbling to parent containers without disabling the default behavior. In the following examples, the `<a/>` will not trigger the alert even though it is contained in a clickable `<div/>`.

```
<script>
  function linkHandler(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
  }
</script>
<div onclick="alert('fail)">
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" onclick="linkHandler(event)">Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

`e.preventDefault()` does not stop the event from bubbling up. You need to add `e.stopPropagation()`, or replace it with `return false`.

You can read more on the [differences between these three in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/211563).

Answer (score 1):

You can use onclick="return false;"

`<a href="#" onclick="return false;">stuff</a>`

Comment: This actually prevents the link from being followed and allows the event on the parent element to be triggered, so it does the opposite of what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Its better practice to register an event handler, but if you just want something very simple do this:

```
  <a href="hello.com" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">Here!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `return false;` or make sure your function is using `e` as an argument

```
$("#clickable a").click(function(e){
   //stuff
   e.preventDefault;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer requires jQuery. To do it inline in vanilla Javascript, you can use the [event](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-window-extensions) property of the global object (window), which is supported by [all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_window_event). You can [omit](https://off-tokyo.medium.com/understanding-javascript-window-object-cb0f082636e8) `window.` when referring to its properties.

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">
```

The Mozilla docs describe the status of this property as [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event), but WhatWG just says developers are [strongly encouraged](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-window-extensions) to use the alternative below. So here is the officially sanctioned way to do this:

```
<a id="mylink" href="https://stackoverflow.com">
<script>
  document.getElementById('mylink').addEventListener('click', evt => {
    evt.stopPropagation()   
  })
</script>
```

Seriously? I’ve made my choice. You can too.