# Kendo Mobile MVVM ListView with click binding on <UL> and detailbutton

Tags: kendo-ui

Trying to do something simple.  A Kendo UI Mobile `ListView` with with a click binding on the `UL` (MVVM) and a `detailbutton` in the list item template.  The `click` binding should simply call a click handler function in the view model - this works as expected.  The `detailbutton` should open an `actionsheet` - this does not work as expected.  What happens is that the click handler fires.

If I can identify the "sender" as the detail button, I should be able to simply `return` from the handler without doing anything and have the action sheet pop up.

A couple of questions:

1) Assuming I am approaching this the right way, what is the most reliable way to identify the source of the click - `LI` vs `detailbutton`?

2) If there is a better way to do this, what is it?

I put together a fiddle.  check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/4zvgS/

Comment: The problem is that click events from anchor tags bubble up in JavaScript. Marking as duplicate of another question that should help. This is also an HTML/JS thing, not a Kendo specific issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancel bubbling on an HTML anchor tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335179/cancel-bubbling-on-an-html-anchor-tag)

Comment: I don't think this is quite a duplicate.  It is specific to kendo ui in that I can get it to work by handling both clicks in the the <UL> click handler and doing nothing if what was clicked on was the detailbutton.  This is what question 1) is about.  How can I reliably determine that the detailbutton was the target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a jQuery handler to stop bubbling the event as mentioned in the 'duplicate' that I linked, or you could do something like this to see if the click is coming from a detail button:

```
    if(e.target.hasClass("km-detail")
      || e.target.parent().hasClass("km-detail")) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Checking for the class as you suggest should work but feels as much like a hack as what I came up with, which is to check the "title" attribute: `if (e.target.context.parentElement.title === "more...")` As for preventing the bubbling, I tried that first but didn't have any luck. I will give it another go as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: @user1843640 Did you ever find a better way of handling this functionality? I have the exact same issue but find myself having to use jQuery as the accepted answer suggests

Comment: @Roark I have since moved on from that project and no longer use Kendo UI but I don't recall ever finding a more elegant way to do this.  I encountered several frustrations like this with Kendo UI but it's been a few years now so perhaps the product has improved.